# QT File menu not integrating into title bar

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, ubuntu-15.04

I am writing a basic gui application in QT creator 3.5.1 and I am using QT 5.5. I have downloaded QT/QT creator via their website. I am currently running Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit.

I am running into an issue regarding the integration of the menu bar into the title bar. The issue being that no integration is happening (the menu bar isn't appearing in the title bar) . The menu bar appears where it would have in the past, below the tile bar. Here is an image of what is happening:

[image: file menu problem]

How can I go about resolving this issue?

UPDATE:

I installed qt 5.4.1 via apt-get, and qt creator. When I compile against this, my title bar integration works! So the question is, what is different? The people I am developing with are using QT 5.5.1, and I would like to use the same version as them. Is there something I can do differently this time around?

Comment: You mean you want menu bar to appear on titlebar? I did not use Qt on linux systems, but I think you should implement a custom frame window and create a custom a titlebar. That's what I do on Windows. Check document about  **Qt::FramelessWindowHint**

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. Hmm,  I'm not sure I fully understand. Can you elaborate?  But also, this integration seems automatic in unity. Old applications seem to just work as I am expecting, so I'm wondering if there is just a simpler solution.

Comment: QWidget us a system titlebar by default. And it cannot add other Qt controls to that system titlebar. So you need to use a frameless window and add a custom titlebar. You may check [this](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_project_org_faq#How_can_I_handle_events_in_the_titlebar_and_change_its_color_etc_.3F)

Comment: Are you aware of how the title bar/menu bar integration works in modern versions of Ubuntu/Unity? I understand what you are saying (I think), but I keep getting the feeling we aren't exactly on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

The unique way that i found was in [this blog](http://nsl.cz/enabling-global-menu-in-qt-creator-in-unity-ubuntu-14-04/). He claims that this method works on Qt Creator, but i've tested on Ubuntu 32/64 bits Qt5 apps (developed by me) and it seems to works fine too!

The steps are:

1. Open terminal
2. Enter `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libdbusmenu-qt5-dev`
3. Set current directory with CD command (the appmenu project will live here)
4. Enter command `apt-get source appmenu-qt5`

Now, the blog still using command line but the next steps can be done by opening the project in Qt Creator (the project is on the current directory).

5. Using some text editor (can be Qt Creator of course), edit the following lines of `appmenu/src/src.pro`:

   CONFIG += X11 link_pkgconfig debug

   PKGCONFIG += dbusmenu-qt5 gtk+-2.0

   DESTDIR = ./

to (if you want a dynamic library):

```
CONFIG += X11 link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += dbusmenu-qt5 gtk+-2.0
```

or (if you want a statically linked library):

```
CONFIG += X11 link_pkgconfig static
PKGCONFIG += dbusmenu-qt5 gtk+-2.0
```

6. Open the project with Qt Creator (if you haven't done already) select the mode of build (Release mode seems to be smaller in size) and build.
7. If built succesfully (as a dynamic library), you will have inside your Qt5 installation folder `/plugins/platformthemes` a plugin called `libappmenu-qt5.so`. To get menu integration, just place the lib in a `platformthemes` subfolder of your target app (including Qt Creator).

Or if built succesfully (as a statically linked library), you will have inside your Qt5 installation folder `/plugins/platformthemes` a file `libappmenu-qt5.a`. This is the static library. To integrate it with your app, add to your project file:

```
QT       +=  core-private gui-private platformsupport-private dbus widgets

LIBS     += $$[QT_INSTALL_DATA]/plugins/platformthemes/libappmenu-qt5.a

CONFIG    += X11 link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += dbusmenu-qt5 gtk+-2.0
```

And to your `main.cpp`:

```
#include <QtPlugin>

Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(AppMenuPlatformThemePlugin)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
...
```

And this should be the result:

[image: Qt Creator]

**Edit (valid when building as dynamic library)**: Note that you wouldn't need to recompile your Qt apps nor Qt Creator .

For Qt Creator you need to place `libappmenu-qt5.so` in your Qt Installation folder: `/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platformthemes`

If you want to redistribute your Qt application, just share inside the folder of your executable the folder `platformthemes` with `libappmenu-qt5.so` inside it. Like any other Qt plugin.

**Edit 2:** Is also possible to build a statically linked plugin, if you don't want extra dependencies.

Comment: I am not sure I follow what you mean with the `platformthemes` sub folder of my target app. It seems to make sense to me that if the QT Creator application is missing menu integration, this would work, but I am not sure how to make this work for an application I am writing in QT Creator. Do you mean I should create such a folder in the source code of the application I am writing, and copy the .so file to it? Will my application then still compile to a single executable file?

Comment: @byteofthat: Sorry for being unclear, please see my edit.

Comment: So with this method I can't make a single executable file I can distribute?

Comment: @byteofthat: With my first answer, you need an extra dependecy. But I've added a static linking approach to my answer with no extra dependecies.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set "**nativeMenuBar**" property of **QMenuBar** Object is **false**.
Because this property has the default value is **true**.